# CA 2225 while overloading long operator

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, overloading, fxcop

I am trying to overload long operator.

```
public static implicit operator long (Abc abc)
{
      .....
}
```

Code analysis gives CA2225 for it.

> Operator overloads have named alternates. Provide a method named
>   'ToXXX' or 'FromXXX' as an alternate for operator 'FileTime.implicit
>   operator long(FileTime)'.

Can someone help?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182355.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sk3x8a7(v=vs.71).aspx  Basically just add a `public static long ToLong(Abc abc)` method.

Comment: The error message and the help document for the error seem clear enough. What _specifically_ are you having trouble figuring out? Did you try following the advice in the error message? I.e. _"Provide a method named 'ToXXX' or 'FromXXX' as an alternate for operator 'FileTime.implicit operator long(FileTime)'."_

Comment: Peter Duniho.....i m not getting that what will be in the body of this function? the same code i am writing in my original function?? both functions will hav the same body?

Comment: Also do i have to replace my function with this ToXXX or FromXXX function? or  do we keep both the functions?

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment under PSR's answer, you need to add a static method ToLong, and not another implicit operator.

```
public static long ToLong(Abc abc)
{
   // Logic for converting Abc to long here.
}
```

Adding this method along side your implicit operator will resolve your warning.

Answer (score -1):

Add this method to your class along with your method.

```
public static implicit operator long(Abc abc){ }

public static implicit operator Tolong(Abc abc){ }
```

Comment: Tolong is not a type and cannot be part of an implicit operator. You need a static method named ToLong.